# Cast Type not Specified Error C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to insert some values into a chart from a database. the first column (X axis) is a  String type and the second column ( Y Axis) is float type.  I keep getting this error "Cast Type not specified"when ever i press the button. Please help

```
  private void ViewGraphBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      try 
      { 
          Query = "SELECT *  FROM Products;";
          Reader = conn.ExecuteStatement(Query);

          while (Reader.Read())
          {
              this.chart1.Series["Series1"]
                         .Points.AddXY(Reader.GetString(1), Reader.GetInt64(4));
          }
      }
      catch (Exception ex) 
      { 
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
      }
  }
```

Comment: A float should probably be cast to a Double in C#

Comment: 2cents: select * from Products will be slower. seeing as you only need 2 columns you might as well specify them as it also is best practice.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean "Specified cast is not valid".  I would assume that you need to parse your `X` value into a numeric type, and use the `GetFloat` method to pull `float` data:

```
   this.chart1
       .Series["Series1"]
       .Points
       .AddXY(float.Parse(Reader.GetString(1)),   // <-- parse to float
              Reader.GetFloat(4)
             );
```

Based on your comment, if you need to parse only the numeric characters you can use `Regex.Replace` to remove anything that's not a digit or period:

```
   this.chart1
       .Series["Series1"]
       .Points
       .AddXY(float.Parse(Regex.Replace(Reader.GetString(1),@"[^\d|\.]","")),   // <-- parse to float
              Reader.GetFloat(4)
             );
```

Comment: Thank you .. that seems to work but now I get an error saying :  Input string was not in a correct format ... any advice??

Comment: Does `Reader.GetString(1)` represent a valid `float` value?  Are there `null`s in that column?

Comment: Also remember that the `GetXXXX` methods use zero-based indexing, go `GetString(1)` returns the _second_ column from the `SELECT *` result.    As suggested it would be safer to explicitly select the column you need and use `GetString(0)` and `GetFloat(1)`.

Comment: sorry, Reader.GetString(1) represents a String Value and there are no nulls in the column.

Comment: But does the _string_ represent a valid _float_ value for ALL products?  e.g. `123.45`?  The error indicates that there are some strings that cannot be parsed to floats.

Comment: oh sorry ... yeah there are some values in the column that contain both Letters and numbers.

Comment: So what do you want to do with those?  skip them?  strip out the letters?